# Update only some fields received by JSON on symfony

Tags: php, symfony4, isset

I am trying to find a way to avoid checking each field if it exists using **if isset()** when updating an entity.

Details:

I have an entity: ***Adresse*** that contains the fields: Id - Libelle - Address - Addressesuite

during the update I send my data by JSON:

> {
>     "libelle" : "update",
>     "adresse" : "test",
>     "adressesuite" : " test"
>   }

the problem is that I have to check the three fields using **if isset** to do an update

```
 if (isset($data['libelle'])) { $adresse->setLibelle($data['libelle']); }
 if (isset($data['Adresse'])) { $adresse->setAdresse($data['Adresse']); }
 .
 .
 .
```

Is it possible to update **only** the fields sent by json! for example if I send only Libelle, then only the field Libelle which will be modified, without needing to make isset several times!

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57248682/symfony-4-api-rest-put-map-data-to-database-entity/57251035#57251035

Comment: First of all thank u, but i don't know which field will be updated to work with groups, cuz sometimes only the libelle field will  be updated and sometimes two fields or more !!

Comment: It's exactly the same problem in this post, you need to use the Symfony serializer (with object_to_populate option) and validator component. you don't need to kwon witch field will be update or not because the serializer will merge your object  in database with sent data.

Comment: i didn't get that , cuz when i see groups={"user_create", "user_update"} , it means that all the fields with that annotations will be concerned no ?